# Angular is removing index.aspx from url in version 6 and 7

Tags: angular, sharepoint

I'm having a problem with the version 6 and 7 of angular. I think the problem come from the new configuration way to build the project...

The problem is that I deploy my app in a SharePoint File Libs and while I try to access my web site, I'm loosing the index.aspx in the url but it's pretty important for navigation

URL expected:

```
www.mysharepointurl.com/App/index.aspx/#/home
```

But after angular load i get

```
www.mysharepointurl.com/App/#/home
```

so if people hit refresh/back/forward in the browser they get out of the website.

With Angular 5, I didn't have this problem, so i guess it's coming from the new configuration way to build the project.

Can anyone help or point me out what could be the problem?

Comment: do you have a `<base href="/" >` in your index.aspx? I've never done this before but you may need to have something in there like `<base href="/app/index.aspx" >` or if your using in the CLI use the --base-href parameter.

Comment: I've added the /app/index.aspx in the basehref but it make the css and other scripts failing to load because the path to other asset is really in /app/

Comment: So the base href is  /app/ actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i've found it after so many hours to research...

BaseHref = '/app/index.aspx/'

DeployUrl = '/app/'